# What is the easiest way to parametrise Exception message?

Tags: java, exception

I have simple class to calculate perimeter of triangle:

```
public double calculatePerimeter(int a, int b, int c) {
double perimeter, o;
int[] tab = {a, b, c};
Arrays.sort(tab);
if (a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0) {
    throw new TriangleParameterException("Length of the side should be greater than zero");
} else if (tab[0] + tab[1] <= tab[2]){
    throw new TriangleParameterException("Sum of shorter sides should be greater than longest side");
} else {
  perimeter = a + b + c;
}
return perimeter;}}
```

what is the simplieast way to parametrise message to display which side of triangle is <= 0?

Comment: Do you mean you need to print a or b or c whichever is <= 0?

Comment: `Math.min(Math.min(a,b), c)`. This will of course return one value. What if two values are negative?

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet `Math.min()` returns the smallest number from the given numbers, NOT if those numbers are `<=0` as OP has requested.

Comment: @px06 If one of the values is <= 0 then it will give you that value. And this is being done inside the `if` statement, so of course one of them has to be <= 0

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet It still doesn't make sense to use this because it doesn't return which param is `<=0`, your proposition is simply a replacement for the existing `if` statement.

Comment: @SMA I need to print all values that are <=0 so it's a bit difficult

Comment: I also have the hint. In this case this construction can be used:
`void validate (int param, String msg){
if(param <=0){

throw new TriangleParameterException(String.format(msg,param));
}
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using conditional operator in java.

`throw new TriangleParameterException(((a<=0)?"a is less then zero":(b<=0?"b is less then zero":"c is less then zero")));`

If you want to check for more then one variable, then also it is possible like above but the solution is little bit crazy:

```
throw new TriangleParameterException(((a<=0&&b<=0&&c<=0)?"a, b, c is less then zero":((a<=0&&b<=0)?"a, b is less then zero":((b<=0&&c<=0)?"b, c is less then zero":((a<=0&&c<=0)?"a, c is less then zero":((a<=0)?"a is less then zero":(b<=0)?"b is less then zero":"c is less then zero"))))));
```

Comment: @Mirek did you tried?? Does this solution works for you??

Comment: @SachinSarawagi works for single values. What about more than one <=0?

Comment: @Mirek I thought that only one variable will be <=0. Let me check how to solve more then one <=0 condition.

Comment: @Mirek. The solution could go crazy, I dont know whether you will like the answer or not but it could be `throw new FileNotFoundException(((a<=0&&b<=0&&c<=0)?"a, b, c is less then zero":((a<=0&&b<=0)?"a, b is less then zero":((b<=0&&c<=0)?"b, c is less then zero":((a<=0&&c<=0)?"a, c is less then zero":((a<=0)?"a is less then zero":(b<=0)?"b is less then zero":"c is less then zero"))))));`. :)) This will take care of all three <=0, two <=0 and one <=0. If you like the answer I will edit my answer.